# Segfault creating doubly linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to read numbers from the text file and create a doubly linked list. I have a decent understanding of doubly linked lists work in theory but I am struggling with the application. I know I am probably trying to dereference a NULL pointer or pointing out of range. But, I can't seem to figure out where exactly.

It outputs the first number and then gives me a segfault somewhere at the `if`/`else` statements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev; 
};

struct list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    struct list *l = NULL;
    FILE *fileptr;
    char filename[20], num[3];

    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    fileptr = fopen (filename, "r");

    while(fscanf(fileptr, "%s", num) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Number is: %d\n", atoi(num));
        temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("HELLO 1\n");
        temp->val = atoi(num);
        printf("HELLO 2\n");

        if(l->tail == NULL)
        {
            l->head = temp;
            l->tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            l->tail->next = temp;
            temp->prev = l->tail;
            l->tail = temp;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I usually complaint about lack of indentation - but this is extreme indentation

Comment: @EdHeal Is that bad? I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: `if(l->tail == NULL)` - what do you suppose happens the first time around when l is NULL?

Comment: Indent by 3/4 characters is better - but at least you have the idea

Comment: @500-InternalServerError As far as my understanding goes, it will assign temp to both - head and tail in the first time. Beyond that, it would not be NULL anymore and would go to the else bit.

Answer (score 1):

struct list *l = NULL; is wrong as you have not allocated any memory to l

You can either do

```
 struct list *l = ( struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
l->head = NULL;
l->tail = NULL;
```

OR you can try

```
struct list l = {0}; and later use l.head or l.tail
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a ton!

Comment: @Ardzard Great it helped. Can you please upvote it :) if you like.

Comment: I tried that in the first place but it won't let me since I am new here. Sorry!

Comment: @Ardzard Thanks once again :)

Comment: It should be noted that in the first case you have to deallocate the `list` pointed to by `l` using `free`, in the second you must not (also, `l` has visibility only in the current function).